# How would I make the enemy go towards me?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I've made this basic 2D game and want the enemy to go towards me. I'm new to the location part and just took the code from another post for my movement but can't figure out how to make it move towards me.

```
        private void EnemyAttack_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Enemy.Location = new Point(Enemy.Location.X +Player.Location.X, Enemy.Location.Y +Player.Location.Y);
        }
```

If anyone could show me or link a post explaining how I could do it that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess whats going on here. SInce you gave such a tinu snippet of code. I assume this

```
 | 100
 |
 |               enemy(40,50)
 |
 |
 |
y| 
 |
 |   me(10,10)
 |______________________________________
0,0                     x             100
```

is you battlefield and you want enemy to move a bit towards 'me', - you dont want it all at once since this is a timer tick.

So lets move 10% for each tick

```
    enemy new x coord = en old xcoord - ((en old xcoord - my x coord) / 10)
    enemy new y coord = en old ycoord - ((en old ycoord - my y coord) / 10)
```

in code

```
     var newx = Enemy.Location.X - ((Enemy.Location.X - Player.Location.X)/10);
     var newy = Enemy.Location.Y - ((Enemy.Location.Y - Player.Location.Y)/10);
     Enemy.Location = new Point(newx, newy);
```